# Utilizar URL amigável sem navegação de pasta

Tags: php, htaccess, url, url-amigável

Preciso identificar o usuário utilizando url amigável, por exemplo: `https://site.com.br/usuario/sistema.php`

Como consigo fazer essa identificação, tendo em vista que não haverá qualquer pasta particular para navegação do cliente individual. Eu já tenho o sistema pronto, então a solução ideal não seria mexer na estrutura dele

Answer (score 0):

Devo pressupor que esteja usando `$_GET`, então basta inserir isto em seu .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^usuario(|/)$ sistema.php
RewriteRule ^usuario/(.*)$ sistema.php?id=$1
```

Suas urls ficarão assim, como exemplo:

`https://site.com.br/usuario/1`